# After login show users information

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I don't really get how to show information after user logins. I have two labels: name and family name in database and in the app itself. This is my script for authorization and I have tried different ways to show full info after login, but all that things does not work.

```
SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-RIK4EDG\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=elearningapp;Integrated Security=True");
string query = "Select * from users Where username = '" + usernameTxtBox.Text.Trim() + " 'and password = '" + passwordTxtBox.Text.Trim() + "'" ;
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlCon);
DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dtbl);
```

Comment: Does anything exist in the `dtbl` table? Also, your code is vulnerable to sql injection, use parameters. On another note, you shouldn't be storing actual passwords either...

Comment: You don't need that query at all. Your application has *already* logged in using the end user's account. That's what `Integrated Security=True` is about. You don't need a username or password at all. If you want to retrieve the logged-in user's details, you should 1) save them under the user's Windows account name and 2) retrieve them using the end user's account name.

Comment: You can get the current user with [WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.getcurrent?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Security_Principal_WindowsIdentity_GetCurrent).

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ, yes, it has data and I know that the code sucks ))) I will be working on that later when I learn how to do it XD.

Comment: @Andrew, profile page to show personal info after login.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, cool will do so and will check it out.